# Where can I find language source strings that are displayed in terminal for messages, warnings, errors etc

Tags: command-line, language-support, locale

There are 2 variants of language mixed up together and I'd like to see if some changes could be made.

Strings that you can see in terminal as an output when you run a command like for example

`sudo apt upgrade`

Where is the source for output strings like

> need to get

> Do you want to continue

or

> leyendo lista de paquetes

below I attached small screenshots so that it can be clear what I want to find (it's only an arbitrary example),

[English example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n4YEe.png),
[Spanish example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RfVJS.png)

Comment: You may find the discussion here helpful: [Ubuntu Internationalization Guide](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuDevelopment/Internationalisation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not one place for all strings which show up in terminal. It depends on which package(s) are providing the command you run.

This is the list of the translation templates with the Spanish translations:

https://translations.launchpad.net/ubuntu/jammy/+lang/es

As regards your example, `sudo apt upgrade`, it's probably the `apt` template.

```
$ echo $(LANGUAGE=es gettext -d apt 'Do you want to continue?')
¿Desea continuar?
```

Comment: Thank you for the details!